# Flutter value notifier not working with list of files

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

In my app I'm using the `photo_manager` package to make a custom image picker. then when i use the `ValueNotifier` it's not doing anything. what i want to do is to listen for changes and update the ui accordingly.

value notifier class

```
class GalleryValurNotifier {
  ValueNotifier<List<File?>> selectedAssets = ValueNotifier<List<File?>>([]);

  void addNotifier(File? file) {
    selectedAssets.value.add(file);
  }

  void clearNotifier() {
    selectedAssets.value.clear();
  }

  void removeNotifier(File? file) {
    selectedAssets.value
        .removeWhere((element) => element.toString() == file.toString());
  }
}
```

then in my stateful widget i created an instance

```
GalleryValurNotifier galleryNotifier = GalleryValurNotifier();
```

and called it as follows

```
 Stack(
                children: [
                  ValueListenableBuilder(
                      valueListenable: galleryNotifier.selectedAssets,
                      builder: (context, value, child) {
                        return Container(
                          width: _width,
                          height: _height * 0.45,
                          child: AssetThumbnail(
                            asset: assets[0],
                            // selected: value,
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                        valueListenable: galleryNotifier.selectedAssets,
                        builder: (context, value, child) {
                          return Container(
                            height: _height * 0.1,
                            width: _width,
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: _width * 0.02),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Get.back();
                                    },
                                    icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.back)),
                                value.isNotEmpty
                                    ? FutureBuilder<File?>(
                                        future: assets[0].file,
                                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                          final file = snapshot.data;
                                          return InkWell(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              if (value != null) {
                                                Get.to(
                                                    ImagePost(images: value));
                                              } else {
                                                // Get.to(ImagePost(images: selectedAssets));
                                              }
                                            },
                                            child: Row(
                                              children: [
                                                Text("NEXT"),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  width: _width * 0.02,
                                                ),
                                                Icon(CupertinoIcons.check_mark)
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        })
                                    : Container()
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

and in the thumbnail widget i called the function, but it's not updating not even assigning the value to it.

```
onTap: () {
final idx = galleryNotifier.selectedAssets.value.indexWhere(
                        (element) => element.toString() == file.toString());

                    if (idx >= 0) {
                      setState(() {
                        galleryNotifier.removeNotifier(file);
                      });
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        galleryNotifier.addNotifier(file);
                      });
                    }

}
```

help me here

Answer (score 0):

ValueNotifier uses equality to detect changes, so the dart compiler will not notice any change if you only change the values of the list, because the list object keeps the same.

You will need to create a new modified list, something like this:

```
class GalleryValurNotifier {
  ValueNotifier<List<File?>> selectedAssets = ValueNotifier<List<File?>>([]);

  void addNotifier(File? file) {
    selectedAssets.value = List.from(selectedAssets.value)..add(file);
  }

  void clearNotifier() {
    selectedAssets.value = [];
  }

  void removeNotifier(File? file) {
    selectedAssets.value = List.from(selectedAssets.value)..removeWhere((element) => element.toString() == file.toString());
  }
}
```